# Is it possible to form some kind of loop from this code?

Tags: php, loops

I need to create a loop with different action code for every day on monthly basis. That's mean for every month I have to run unique code.

```
$date="2012-05-31";

for ($i=1; $i<31; $i++) {
    $newdate=str_replace('-', '/', $date);
    $codeDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($newdate . "+".$i." days"));
    if ($i==1) echo "\n"."new cycle start:  ".$codeDate; 
    /* UNIQUE CODE FOR JUNE 2012 */ 
}
echo "\n"."new cycle end:  ".$codeDate."\n \n"; 


for ($i=1; $i<32; $i++) {
    $newdate=str_replace('-', '/', $codeDate);
    $codeDate1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($newdate . "+".$i." days"));
    if ($i==1) echo "\n"."new cycle start:  ".$codeDate1; 
    /* UNIQUE CODE FOR JULY 2012 */ 
}
echo "\n"."new cycle end:  ".$codeDate1."\n \n"; 

for ($i=1; $i<32; $i++) {
    $newdate=str_replace('-', '/', $codeDate1);
    $codeDate2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($newdate . "+".$i." days"));
    if ($i==1) echo "\n"."new cycle start:  ".$codeDate2; 
    /* UNIQUE CODE FOR AUGUST 2012 */ 
}
echo "\n"."new cycle end:  ".$codeDate2;
```

I need such approach for several years. Is it some way to do this with loops or some other tools.

Comment: So you need a unique code every month, on going for many years?

Comment: @Dammeul Exact. I need a code for every day of a month which depends from specific month-year.

Comment: I would use a database myself, add the current month and year as seperate columns, as well as the code, then check if it is the same month and year, and grab a code you've generated but added into the databsae.  If it's not the same monh, or year etc. insert a new entry with a newly generated code,a nd start getting that in your first query, which you can then use for that month...

Comment: You could add in code to just update the pervious, or keep records of the previous, and only keep the last 3 month etc. etc. so you don't just keep adding to the database

Comment: Can definitely be done with hardcoding and such... but that's nasty.

Comment: @Dammeul It is the same as I do just you use SQL instead of php. But if you need 100 years, than you have to create 1200 columns. Not really useful.

Comment: No, you would need to create maybe 3/4 columns... id, month, year, token...

Once created, you check the current month, and current date, against the table, and get the token back... if the date or year is different, then you run another insert that inserts the next id, month, year and token, and then return that token for use.  Then any other calls once this is done for that month and year will get that token, until the next month and year, where another is generated.

Comment: Then every 4/5th insert, clear out older entries to keep the table small, orrrrr... when mvoing into a new month or year, update the row and just keep one record

Comment: @Dammeul Yes, indeed. It is excellent finding. I have not caught it from a first time. If you write it as an answer I will mark it as perfect solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to work through this, as it may produce errors as not test just cold wrote it... but along these lines is what you are after (though this doesn't take into account removing the data so you're table doesn't just grow and grow).

```
$month = date('m');
$year = date('y');    
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT token FROM token_table WHERE year = $year AND month = $month ");

if(count($result) > 0) {
   $token = $result[0]['token'];
} else {
   $token = generateYourTokenHoweverYouDoIt();
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO token_table (month, year, token) VALUES ('$month', '$year', '$token')");
}

//Use token.
```

Also, you need to make sure any variable you use in a database query is sanitised for security... generally just ones that could come from user input, so should be okay here... but always good to think about security when working with databases...

Look at: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

and: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Personally, I use PDO, but it's longer to write and mysqli comes more naturally too me. But look into both.

Comment: Excellent solution. I really like it. Thank you for your support and attention to this question.

Comment: That's no problem at all, happy to help!